# protractor get div element by title

Tags: protractor, element, title

What is the best way to find a div element by his title, 'ACTIVITY_1':

```
<div class="col-xs-3 no-margin no-padding type..." data-ng-class="..." data-ng-click="..." title="ACTIVITY_1"
```

thx

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: I used the answer of @Ajinkya Shukla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a CSS selector:

```
element(by.css('div[title=ACTIVITY_1]'));
```

Or, with a `$` shortcut:

```
$('div[title=ACTIVITY_1]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command too

```
element(by.css(`a[title="${ACTIVITY_1}"]`))
```