# How to select a element if value/title contains a text

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have been trying to find out on how I can grab the element if a value contains "6 months". Here is few example and as we can see all of these values has the word 6 months and this is different scenarios of course so I don't want to click all of them but I gave example of different banktype that I need to click

```
<input type="button" aria-label="AMEX 6 months Extended Payment Plan" title="AMEX 6 months Extended Payment Plan" value="AMEX 6 months Extended Payment Plan" class="pm-button pp-content-btn pm-button-half">

<input type="button" aria-label="DBS IPP 6 months 0%" title="DBS IPP 6 months 0%" value="DBS IPP 6 months 0%" class="pm-button pp-content-btn pm-button-half">

<input type="button" aria-label="UOBSG IPP 6 months 0%" title="UOBSG IPP 6 months 0%" value="UOBSG IPP 6 months 0%" class="pm-button pp-content-btn pm-button-half">
```

and I wonder if its possible to click on a element if the value/title contains the word "6 months" inside it?

EDIT : Using protractor for testing

Comment: Use an attribute query selector with a substring matching selector, like  `document.querySelectorAll('[title*="6 months"]')`

Comment: @Teemu I think my problem is that I can't use querySelectorAll in protractor :(

Comment: Maybe this gives an idea, but I'm not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108686/protractor-get-div-element-by-title

Comment: @tenkmilan I believe that is more if we are aware of what exact title we want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what [by.cssContainingText](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) does (partial text matcher in conjunction with css)

```
let elem = element(by.cssContainingText('[style]', '6 months'));
```

REVISION

1 way for doing what you need, but very inefficient... You may use `.filter` against elementArrayFinder several times until you narrow down the results to the element you need

But I'd look for the element you need by 2 parameters

```
let $elem = (bank, range) => element(by.xpath(`//input[contains(.,"${bank}") and contains(.,"${range}")]`));
```

Correct the xpath as needed. But essentially it looks for an `input` element that partially matches anything (attribute, text etc) with first parameter AND the second one

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using xpaths with the contains function like so:

```
element(by.xpath('//input[contains(@title,"6 months")]');
```

The [contains function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) is very useful for locating elements which contain certain text either in an attribute or in the node itself.

Comment: Ohhhh this one works! Amazing, didnt thought I could do it that pretty easy!

Answer (score 1):

since you can't use the querySelectorAll, you might find this function helpful:

in case you don't depend on the element name:

```
FindByAttributeValue("Attribute-Name", "Attribute-Value");
```

or in case you do:

```
FindByAttributeValue("Attribute-Name", "Attribute-Value", "div");
```

and the full function implementation:

```
function FindByAttributeValue(attribute, value, element_type){
    element_type = element_type || "*";
    var All = document.getElementsByTagName(element_type);
    for (var i = 0; i < All.length; i++){
        if (All[i].getAttribute(attribute) == value){
            return All[i];
        }
    }
}
```

full answer came from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21329963/11870303)

Comment: But if I understod correctly, the attributes needs to be exact matching to be valid, dont it in this case?